# Code works during debugging step thru but not when running to breakpoints

Tags: perl, debugging

Ok, so I'm thoroughly confused.  I have some code that basically reads in a ftp log file and separates it into flows.  I seem to be having inconsistent output though depending on whether or not I step thru the code or simply have it execute or go from breakpoint to breakpoint.  If I have it step thru it performs correctly and the hash array I have is created correctly.  If however I run it from breakpoint to breakpoint it seems to create the hash and array incorrectly.  I would think it would not matter how it's debugged, it would still come out with the same output.  I'm using Eclipse as the IDE and EPIC as the debugger.

Here's an example of the input:

```
Dec  1 23:59:57 ftp1 sshd[5389]: Accepted publickey for test1 from 192.168.0.1 port 18432 ssh2
Dec  1 23:59:57 ftp1 sftp-server[5392]: Starting sftp-server logging for user test1.
Dec  1 23:59:57 ftp1 sftp-server[5392]: bad value 0 for SFTP_UMASK, turning umask control off.
Dec  1 23:59:57 ftp1 sftp-server[5392]: realpath .
Dec  1 23:59:57 ftp1 sftp-server[5392]: realpath /prod/data/006
Dec  1 23:59:57 ftp1 sftp-server[5392]: opendir /prod/data/006
Dec  1 23:59:59 ftp1 sshd[5394]: Accepted publickey for test2 from 192.168.0.1 port 18433 ssh2
Dec  1 23:59:59 ftp1 sftp-server[5397]: Starting sftp-server logging for user test2.
Dec  1 23:59:59 ftp1 sftp-server[5397]: bad value 0 for SFTP_UMASK, turning umask control off.
Dec  1 23:59:59 ftp1 sftp-server[5397]: realpath .
Dec  2 00:00:00 ftp1 sftp-server[5397]: realpath /prod/data/228
Dec  2 00:00:00 ftp1 sftp-server[5397]: opendir /prod/data/228
```

Here's the output I get when I step thru the code which is how it should be:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '5397' => {
                      '23:5' => [
                                  'Dec  1 23:59:59 ftp1 sshd[5394]: Accepted publickey for test1 from 192.168.0.1 port 18433 ssh2
',
                                  'Dec  1 23:59:59 ftp1 sftp-server[5397]: Starting sftp-server logging for user test2.
',
                                  'Dec  1 23:59:59 ftp1 sftp-server[5397]: bad value 0 for SFTP_UMASK, turning umask control off.
',
                                  'Dec  1 23:59:59 ftp1 sftp-server[5397]: realpath .
',
                                  'Dec  2 00:00:00 ftp1 sftp-server[5397]: realpath /prod/data/228
',
                                  'Dec  2 00:00:00 ftp1 sftp-server[5397]: opendir /prod/data/228
'
                                ]
                    },
```

Here is how it is when I'm using breakpoints or running the code straight out, as you see it creates an extra hash ' ':

```
$VAR1 = {
          '5397' => {
                      '' => [
                              'Dec  2 00:00:00 ftp1 sftp-server[5397]: opendir /prod/data/228
'
                            ],
                      '23:5' => [
                                  'Dec  1 23:59:59 ftp1 sshd[5394]: Accepted publickey for test2 from 192.168.0.1 port 18433 ssh2
',
                                  'Dec  1 23:59:59 sslmftp1 sftp-server[5397]: Starting sftp-server logging for user test2.
',
                                  'Dec  1 23:59:59 sslmftp1 sftp-server[5397]: bad value 0 for SFTP_UMASK, turning umask control off.
',
                                  'Dec  1 23:59:59 sslmftp1 sftp-server[5397]: realpath .
',
                                  'Dec  2 00:00:00 sslmftp1 sftp-server[5397]: realpath /prod/data/228
'
                                ]
                    },
```

Here's the code segment in question:

```
#----------------------
    # Search by IP address
    #----------------------
    sub ip(){
        my $username;
        my $tmpline;
        my %pids;
        my $hhmm;
        my $tmpuser;
        my %finished; 
        my @error;

        my $infile = $searchfile;
        open (INPUT, $infile) or die "Couldn't read $infile.\n";

        if ($STYPE == "ip" && ($SEARCH =~ m/^([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})/)) {
            # pull username and times from matched lines
            while(my $line = <INPUT>) {
                if($line =~ m/(password|publickey)\sfor\s(\w+)\sfrom\s(([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3}))/){
                    my $tmpIP = $3;
                    $username = $2;
                    if ($tmpIP =~ $SEARCH){
                        $tmpline = $line;
                    }
                }
                if ($tmpline){
                    if($line =~ m/(Starting\ssftp-server\slogging\sfor\suser\s(\w+))/){
                        $tmpuser = $2;
                        if ($tmpuser =~ $username){
                            if ($line =~ /sftp-server\[(.*?)\]/){   
                                my $mPID = $1;
                                if($line =~ /(\d{2})\:(\d)/){
                                    my $time = $1 . ":" . $2;
                                    $pids{$mPID} = $time;
                                    $pids{$mPID} = {$pids{$mPID} => []};
                                    $finished{$mPID} = 0;
                                    push @{$pids{$mPID}{$time}}, $tmpline;
                                    push @{$pids{$mPID}{$time}}, $line;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        if($line =~ /sftp-server\[(.*?)\]/){
                            my $mPID = $1;
                            if(exists $pids{$mPID}){
                                if($line =~ /(\d{2})\:(\d)/){
                                    my $time = $1 . ":" . $2;
                                    if((exists $pids{$mPID}{$time})&&($finished{$mPID} != 1)){
                                        push @{$pids{$mPID}{$time}}, $line;

                                    } else {
                                        if($finished{$mPID} != 1){
                                            if(exists $pids{$mPID}){
                                                my $mtime = each $pids{$mPID};
                                                push @{$pids{$mPID}{$mtime}}, $line;
                                                if($line =~ m/(sftp-server\sfinished)/){
                                                    $finished{$mPID} = 1;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }else {
                            if($line =~ /$SEARCH/){
                                push @error, $line if not ($line =~ /Accepted/);
                            }
                        }
                    } 

                } 
                #print $line . '\n';        
            }

        } else {
            print "I'm sorry, this is not a valid IP address, please try again.\n";
        }

        close (INPUT);
```

I would appreciate any help you could provide, I'm completely stumped at the moment.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: well, I was able to get around this issue by fixing it further down but it's only a bandage, I'm still curious as to why this is happening.  Any suggestions would help.  Thanks!

Comment: An empty hash key is often caused by an uninitialized value warning, which could be caught with 'use warnings;'. You can turn that into a stacktrace with Carp::Always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kaoru pointed out, the empty hash key is caused by an uninitialized value. This uninitialized value is generated by line 93:

> my $mtime = each $pids{$mPID};

Your use of each is somewhat unconventional. Perl's [each](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) function is generally used to iterate over arrays or hashes. In your case, the first call returns the value you are interested in (the first key), but the second call returns `undef` as no key is added or deleted from the hash, nor are the `keys` or `values` functions called. You can see that this really is the issue by adding this code snippet after line 93:

`if($mtime){
    print "mtime defined\n";
}else{
    print "mtime undefined\n";
    my $test = each $pids{$mPID};<br>
    print "non-empty again\n" if $test;<br>
}`

I have never used EPIC, but I can only assume that it somehow resets [each](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html)'s iterator while inspecting values. This theory is consistent with the difference you observe between line by line stepping and executing between breakpoint. It might be interesting to reproduce this side-effect in a more simple piece of code and submit it to EPIC's developers for review. This is not the kind of side-effect I expect from a debugger and might very well be a bug.